# Mobile React Native Image upload issue

Tags: reactjs, api, mobile, native

Actually I am getting issue when passing image in byte to api.
It removes the actual byte of base64 by replacing like /hjbjsb...hdjhh= which 
base64 string is not converted into image at API functions.

So Please provide the way to do this.

Thank You
Kapil Verma

Comment: You question is not clear. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: are you encrypting the base64 string?

Comment: Yes want to encrypting base64 string in react native